# How do I get player Depth from the data Kinect SDK C#?

Tags: c#, kinect

Doing a group project trying to make something happen when the player (specifically the player) is near/far so we wrote this function. (We're not allowed to use the skeleton features)

```
private void FindDepth(DepthImageFrame depthFrame)
    {

        short[] rawDepthData = new short[depthFrame.PixelDataLength];
        depthFrame.CopyPixelDataTo(rawDepthData);

        Byte[] pixels = new byte[depthFrame.Height * depthFrame.Width * 4];

        for (int depthIndex = 0; depthIndex < rawDepthData.Length; depthIndex++)
        {
            int player = rawDepthData[depthIndex] & DepthImageFrame.PlayerIndexBitmask;
            int depth = rawDepthData[depthIndex] >> DepthImageFrame.PlayerIndexBitmaskWidth;

            if (player > 0)
            {
                playerDepth = rawDepthData[depthIndex];
            }

        }

    }
```

Why doesn't this properly grab the player's depth by grabbing one pixel?

Answer (score 3):

A depth pixel is represented as 16 bits. The lower 3 bits provides the player index and rest 13 bits provides the depth e.g. {depth bits}{player index bits}

{0100 1011 1001 0}{010}

thus in order to find player index we AND by DepthImageFrame.PlayerIndexBitmask as displayed below

(0100 1011 1001 0010) AND (0000 0000 0000 0111) = 0000 0000 0000 0010 = 2 i.e. 2nd player

and in order to find distance we shift right by 3 bits which return 13 bits as displayed below
0000 1001 0111 0010 = 2418 i.e. 2418 mm

Answer (score 0):

It is important to remember that the player number values are only added to the depth image if 
skeleton tracking is turned on. If skeleton tracking is turned off, the player number in every depth 
value is set to 0.